# unable to query pymongo by ISODate

Tags: python, pymongo

i am trying to query pymongo using ISODate and string but i keep getting errors

> query = {'createdAt': {'$gt': 'ISODate'('2021-09-01')}}
>
> cursor = col.find(query)

error i get is:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

resolved i didn't need ISODate. This works

```
query = {'createdAt': {'$gt':'2021-09-01'}}

cursor = col.find(query)
```